# Java client use Async.function call child workflow cannot compile if the child workflow method throws exception

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Simply says `Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception`. Try catch does not help. Is the @WorkflowMethod of a workflow allowed to throw any exception at all?

[image]
Child workflow code:

```java
public class ChildWorkflowWorker {
    public interface ChildWorkflow {
        @WorkflowMethod
        String run(String s) throws Exception;
    }

    public static class ChildWorkflowImpl implements ChildWorkflow {

        @Override
        public String run(String s) throws Exception {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Parent workflow code

```java
public class ParentWorkflowWorker {
    public interface ParentWorkflow {
        @WorkflowMethod
        void run();
    }

    public static class ParentWorkflowImpl implements ParentWorkflow {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ChildWorkflowWorker.ChildWorkflow childWorkflow = Workflow.newChildWorkflowStub(ChildWorkflowWorker.ChildWorkflow.class);
            try {
                Promise<String> childPromise = Async.function(childWorkflow::run, "");
                childPromise.get();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous code and checked exceptions don't play well together. Also as child workflow and activity invocations are technically remote method invocations the exceptions that are thrown in the caller are usually not the same original exceptions.

So the adopted solution is to never use checked exceptions in the activity and workflow method signatures.

To avoid unnecessary wrapping you can use [Activity.wrap](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-java-sdk/blob/67c252100daf91c4e65730dac686eaaad4adc9c9/src/main/java/io/temporal/activity/Activity.java#L317) and [Workflow.wrap](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-java-sdk/blob/67c252100daf91c4e65730dac686eaaad4adc9c9/src/main/java/io/temporal/workflow/Workflow.java#L833) methods to rethrow a checked exception. It is going to wrap it in an internal CheckedExceptionWrapper exception which will be automatically unwrapped at the caller.

```
try {
    return someCall();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw Activity.wrap(e);
}
```